# Is there a way to remove that focus on the button in a JOptionPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Is there a way to remove that focus on the button in a `JOptionPanel`? I really want to remove it. I looks a eyesore. There is my code for the `JOptionPanel`

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null,
                mainPanel,
                "CREDITS   (づ￣ ³￣)づ ",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Because removing focus hints from the user helps them, how? If it's really that much of an issue, then perhaps you should consider rolling your own dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you probably need a global event listener, to clear the focus when the message dialog appears. Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;

import javax.swing.FocusManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestFocus {

    private final AWTEventListener focusListener = this::removeFocus;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TestFocus()::initUI);
    }
    
    private void initUI() {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(focusListener, AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Here is no Focus on button", "No focus!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().removeAWTEventListener(focusListener); // to be safe remove it twice.
    }
    
    private void removeFocus(AWTEvent e) {
        if (e instanceof FocusEvent && ((FocusEvent) e).getID() == FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().removeAWTEventListener(focusListener);
            FocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().clearFocusOwner();
        }
    }
}
```